# Passenger 3.x Standalone Binaries Connection Timeout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I am trying to test our gem for Passenger 3.x support but whenever I try to run my application using **bundle exec passenger start** and install the needed data for the Passenger (3.0.21) Standalone Binaries, I am getting a connection time out error.

I am on **Ruby 2.3.0** and **Rails 3.2.22**.

```
# wget -O /tmp/passenger.20190118-7642-1mmkq5k/support.tar.gz http://standalone-binaries.modrails.com/3.0.21-x86_64-ruby2.3.0-linux-gcc7.3.0-1011/support.tar.gz
--2019-01-18 15:08:12--  http://standalone-binaries.modrails.com/3.0.21-x86_64-ruby2.3.0-linux-gcc7.3.0-1011/support.tar.gz
Resolving standalone-binaries.modrails.com (standalone-binaries.modrails.com)... 72.232.173.34
Connecting to standalone-binaries.modrails.com (standalone-binaries.modrails.com)|72.232.173.34|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2019-01-18 15:10:24--  (try: 2)  http://standalone-binaries.modrails.com/3.0.21-x86_64-ruby2.3.0-linux-gcc7.3.0-1011/support.tar.gz
Connecting to standalone-binaries.modrails.com (standalone-binaries.modrails.com)|72.232.173.34|:80... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

I got this 3.0.21 version from their [Github Releases.](https://github.com/phusion/passenger/releases?after=release-3.0.21)

It seems like the site is already down, if so, are there any mirrors for the Passenger 3.x versions? Any thoughts on how else I could test my gem on older versions of Passenger?

Thank you!